# ReferenceError: Cannot access 'savedPost' before initialization

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

My POST method which throws the ReferenceError:

```
postsRouter.post('/:postNumber', async (req, res, next) => {
    const postDate = new Date().toUTCString()
    const post = new Post({
        ...req.body,
        poster: req.body.poster 
            ? (req.body.poster.includes(config.AP) ? req.body.poster.replace(config.AP, '') : req.body.poster) 
            : 'nonamer',
        date: postDate,
        IP: req.socket.remoteAddress,
        admin: req.body.poster.includes(config.AP) ? true : false
    })
    try {
        const [savedPost, updatedBubble] = await Promise.all([
            /* save() doesn't save the post with the new postnumber which it should (see the pre('save') 
            function in the next code block), it's only in the post that is being returned while saving. */
            post.save().catch(e => { console.log('Task 1 failed!'); next(e) }),
            // req.params.postNumber is the postnumber of the bubble a.k.a thread being replied to.
            Post.findOneAndUpdate(
                { postNumber: req.params.postNumber }, 
                { $push: { replies: savedPost.postNumber } })
                .catch(e => { console.log('Task 2 failed!'); next(e) })
        ])
        res.status(201).json(savedPost)
        console.log('!!!!! ' + req.socket.remoteAddress + ' saved a post: ' + JSON.stringify(savedPost))
    } catch (e) {
        next(e)
    }
})
```

Also this mess of a code is in my Post model (which utilizes Counter model):

```
// Increase postnumber in counter collection's sole document, and insert it into new post.
postSchema.pre('save', function(next) {
    let post = this
    const ccc = Counter.findByIdAndUpdate(
        { '_id': 'postNumCounter' },
        { '$inc': { 'currentPostNum': 1 }}, // Works
        { new: true },
        // inserting postnumber not working, fix
        function(error, counter) {
            post.postNumber = counter.currentPostNum
        }
    ) 
    // Not working either
    post.postNumber = ccc.currentPostNum
    next()
})
```

My goal is I simply want to grab the `currentPostNum` after incrementing it, and insert that into the post before saving it.

Comment: Makes sense to me. You're trying to access savedPost in `{ $push: { replies: savedPost.postNumber } })` , yet it's only defined after all promises are resolved. Since I don't know your original indent, I can't quite tell what the fix should be. Probably retrieve savedPost first, then update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved myself. I made the pre('save') function asynchronous as well, and ditched Promise.all in the controller POST method. Now everything works in tandem.

```
postSchema.pre('save', async function (next) {
    let post = this
    const counter = await Counter.findByIdAndUpdate(
        { '_id': 'postNumCounter' },
        { '$inc': { 'currentPostNum': 1 } }, // Works
        { new: true }
    )
    post.postNumber = counter.currentPostNum
    next()
})
```